# How to produce the data points for a circle in Excel using ROW INDIRECT

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2013, vba

[The page linked to here](http://tmehta.com/tmblog/?p=589&cpage=1#comment-2120) has been a great help to me.  The method of using the named function (=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:361"))-1)*PI()/180) to produce the circle data points is very slick compared to my original method that was to calculate them individually, writing them in to rows.

My data set includes some 50k rows of data, each one defining a circle.  The set is divided into 50 groups and I need to plot one circle from each group as selected via a scroll bar controlling a LOOKUP routine.

Please can someone suggest how I might modify the function (=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:361"))-1)*PI()/180) to reduce the number of data points it produces?  I want to reduce the computing load and also, it's not practical to display & format data markers with such high data density.  My existing circles are produced with just 18 coordinate pairs and are satisfactorily rounded.

Thanks in advance.  Steve.

Answer (score 1):

This would give you 19 data points, 0 and 360 as the start/end points with another every 20%

`=(ROW(INDIRECT("1:19"))-1)*PI()/9`